# Filtering an arraylist using first characters of string for Android Application

Tags: java, android

To study android development, I have created an android application called "Contacts", it's basically just a phonebook. I have a list of contacts with first name, last name and phone number. I also have an edittext which I use for filtering the list.

Currently, I can filter the list by finding all entries containing the string inputted in the edittext. For example, I have 3 contacts:

```
Jane Doe
John Doe
John Joseph Smith
```

If I input something like "oe", the list will return John Doe and Jane Doe. Now, I was hoping I could filtering by the initials of the name so if I enter "J S" or "Jo J S", it would return John Joseph Smith but I'm not entirely sure how to start this implementation.

I've overrided FilterResults performFiltering and this is what I ended up with:

```
FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
ArrayList<Contacts> filteredContacts= new ArrayList<Contacts>();

if (constraint!= null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
    for (Contacts contact : unfilteredContacts) {
        String firstname = contact.getFirstname();
        String lastname = contact.getLastname();
        String phone = contact.getNumber();

        if (firstname .toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
                lastname .toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
                phone .contains(constraint.toString())) {
            filteredContacts.add(contact);
        }
    }

    results.values = filteredContacts;
    results.count = filteredContacts.size();
```

What is the best approach in implementing this? Is there any way I can avoid using nested loops for this?

[UPDATE] I ended up using loops for my implementation however my code is acting a bit funny. I've added this snippet to perform the additional filter:

```
String[] splitName = fullname.toLowerCase().split(" ");
String[] initials = constraint.toLowerCase().split(" ");
if (initials.length > 1) {
   for (String nm : splitName) {
       for (String ini : initials) {
           if (nm.startsWith(ini)) { isMatch = true; } 
           else { isMatch = false; }
       }
   }
}
if (isMatch) { filteredContacts.add(contact); }
```

If I enter "J D", it only returns "Jane Doe" even though it should also display "John Doe". What's up with that?

Comment: "but I'm kind of stuck with this" is not a problem description. Please describe exactly what is and isn't working as expected and which errors you are getting. If you get exceptions then also include the stack trace.

Comment: If you want to avoid loops, you should consider implementing an [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index#Computer_science).

Comment: what is temp in your code?

Comment: sorry, it's contraint. I was playing around with my code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the input using space character and check if result array is bigger than one. If yes, there are initials so you have to check them using String's `startsWith()` method.

```
String[] initials = constraint.split(" ");
if (initials.length == 1) {
    //single input, do you 'if' here
} else {
    //initials detected, check every string with 'startsWith()' method
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I played around with my code using this logic but somehow, something weird is happening to my filter. I've updated my code to show my additional filter.

Comment: Hard to say something more, but maybe you should add contact in a loop for every match. Now it looks like you are adding only the first one.

Comment: I was thinking that might be redundant. That entire snippet is inside the for (Contacts contact : unfilteredContacts) loop, i just add contact when my flag is true, but I will try to play around more with the code. Thanks for the suggestion.